# Finding QModelIndex of new entry into Model

Tags: c++, qt, model-view

I have a model that holds a sorted list of integers.  New entries to the model look something like this:

```
if (!causesCollision(iCode))
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), this->rowCount(), this->rowCount());
    this->_codes.append(iCode);
    qSort(this->_codes);
    endInsertRows();

    return true;
}
```

I need the QListView that uses this model to automatically highlight new entries to the model, but currently I am unable to find the index of newly created row.  this->_codes is a QList<int>.

First, I tried the rowsInserted(...) signal, but it only reports that a row was added at the end, not the position within the list that the new item was added.

I've tried something like this:

```
    int iRow = this->_codes.indexOf(iCode);
    QModelIndex index = this->index(iRow, 0);

    emit ModelChanged(index);
```

With the ModelChanged(index) signal connected to the QListView's setCurrentIndex(index) slot, but it did not work.

Comment: What is the `this->_codes`? List?

Comment: if you insert an item and then sort then arg 2 and 3 of beginInsertRows is incorrect (most of the time)

Comment: _codes is a QList<int>.  I updated the body of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `this->_codes` is a list, you can easily get the index of the item you inserted after sorting. I would rewrite your insertion code in the following way:

```
if (!causesCollision(iCode))
{
    // Calculate the insertion position in the list.
    int row = 0;
    while (row < _codes.size() && _codes.at(row) < iCode) {
        row++;
    }
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), row, row + 1);
    _codes.insert(row, iCode); // Always insert sorted.
    endInsertRows();

    return true;
}
```

After this the `rowsInserted()` signal will indicate the right position where the new row has been inserted.

Comment: I changed my method to your suggestion, and I have this slot handling the signal:

`this->_ui.CodeView->setCurrentIndex(this->_model.index(start, 0));`

But it still is not highlighting the code when it gets inserted.  The implementation of the model::index(row, column, parent) method is just `return createIndex(row, column);`

Comment: @TheJubilex, note that setting the current index does not highlight the item. You have to select it.

Comment: I tried `this->_ui.CodeView->selectionModel()->select(this->_model.index(start, 0), QItemSelectionModel::Select);` as well, with the same result. The item still is not highlighted.

Comment: I found the error.  I was trying to setCurrentIndex in different places, and a wrong way was overwriting the correct way.  Marking this solution as correct because it did help find the correct way.

Comment: The code is not fully correct, the third argument of beginInsertRows() should also be just "row".
I.e. it is the row index of the last row that gets inserted. So for a single row insertion second and third argument are the same value.